# How to insert data from the same row by extracting text in Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle

I have the below table:
(AddressID,ShortAddress,FullAddress).
Now, The FullAdress column normally contains address like this:
Bellvue East,204-Park Avenue,Zip-203345.
I need to write a script, which will extract the first part before the first ',' in the full address and insert into ShortAddress column.
So, the Table Data before executing the script:

```
AddressID|ShortAddress|FullAddress
 1       |    NULL    |Bellvue East,204-Park Avenue,Zip-203345,United Kingdom
 2       |    NULL    |Salt Lake,Sector-50/A,Noida,UP,India
```

And after executing the script, it should be:

```
AddressID|ShortAddress|FullAddress
     1   |Bellvue East|Bellvue East,204-Park Avenue,Zip-203345,United Kingdom
     2   |Salt Lake|Salt Lake,Sector-50/A,Noida,UP,India
```

I need to write it in Oracle PL/SQL.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to do that in a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Try this `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET ShortAddress = COALESCE(SUBSTR(FullAddress, 1, INSTR(FullAddress, ',') - 1),
                            FullAddress)
```

This update query will assign the first CSV term in the full address to the short address.  If no comma be present, then it will assign the entire full address.